# Compare values of two dataframes and substitute them

Tags: r, dataframe

I've two data frames with the same number of rows and columns, `113x159` with this structure:

df1:

```
   1  2  3  4
a AT AA AG CT
b NA AG AT CC
c AG GG GT AA
d NA NA TT TC
```

df2:

```
   1  2  3  4
a NA 23 12 NA
b NA 23 44 12
c 11 14 27 55
d NA NA 12 34
```

I want to compare value to value db1 e db2, and if the value of db 2 is NA and the value of db1 isn't, replace it (also if db1 value is NA and in db2 not). 
At the end, my df has to be this:

```
   1  2  3  4
a NA AA AG NA
b NA AG AT CC
c AG GG GT AA
d NA NA TT CC
```

I've written this if loop but it doesn't work:

```
merge.na<-function(x){
for (i in df2) AND (k in df1){
    if (i==NA) AND (k!=NA)
    k==NA}
```

Any idea?

Comment: You can't do `== NA`. Use `is.na()`

Comment: `is.na(df1) <- is.na(df2)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus better for sure, it works very well. I see that it overlap on the df1, but fortunatly I've got a copy. Ty so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `replace`

```
replace(df1, is.na(df2), NA)
#   X1   X2 X3   X4
#a <NA>   AA AG <NA>
#b <NA>   AG AT   CC
#c   AG   GG GT   AA
#d <NA> <NA> TT   TC
```